# need a shell script to do svn update,svn delete and svn import

Tags: linux, svn

i have created a local repository(svn) on my server.
we do svn update on the repository to fetch the recent drivers(code).The files recieved are in the below form.

1. goto code base and do svn update
2. create a url to this code base and take the files into a log so as to print dynamic messages when you do an svn delete and svn import saying that particular file/files have been imported/deleted.
3. third step is to delete a few files from the repository. svn delete.
4. svn import

   ```
   svn import . file:///home/head/input/exrep/ -m "sync operation from abcrepos" > $file`;

   svn del file:///opt/svn/trunk/input/hyrep/exrep/www/js/nvm/nvmgraph.js -m "removing javascript"
   ```

need a shell script to do the following automatically

problem-into my local repository i always need to do svn import and delete. when new additions are made into the original repo it says "file existing" and will not replace the file with new contents.so script to do above steps to automate the svn update,svn delete and svn import.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a "Vendor Branch" instead ([see the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)). There are scripts and tools to support you mentioned in the docs.